# as3 check if child exists - removeChild();

Tags: actionscript-3, exists, removechild, addchild

The code below creates a MovieClip called "circle" and checks if it exists and deletes it via removeChild();  It removed the circle but the [object MovieClip] is still there.

How can I check if a child is "on stage" or removed using removeChild?

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var circle:MovieClip  = new MovieClip();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF794B);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 30);
circle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(circle);
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);

function test(event:MouseEvent)
{
    trace(circle);
    if(circle)
    {
     trace("Called if Circle");
     removeChild(circle);
    }
    trace(circle);
}
```

Comment: to check if display object is in display list use contains(). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29 . To completly remove object set it to null. circle = null;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check the `circle.stage` property:

```
    if(circle.stage)
    {
        trace("circle is in display list");
        circle.parent.removeChild(circle);  //remove circle from display list
        circle = null //remove reference to the circle, mark it for garbage collection
    }
    else
    {
        trace("circle isn't in display list");
    }
```

Comment: I just used removeChild(circle); This should work for my purposes but why does trace(circle) sill display after its gone? Is there away to remove that? - Also I get this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: You just remove _circle_ from display list, to delete reference to it you should manually set _circle = null_, after that garbage collector will remove the circle from memory.

Comment: or better yet, use `parent` instead of stage.  That way even if one of it's parents isn't on the stage, it'll still get removed.

Comment: it's slightly different to check the _stage_ and _parent_, if you need to check whether child are withing stage or not check the _stage_, if you just need to remove _child_ from parent,no matter is child on the stage or not, check only _parent_.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use the `contains` function of a DisplayObject.

```
if (contains(circle))
{
    // The circle is contained by the current clip
    removeChild( circle );
    // Remove the reference to the clip 
    // (optional, if you don't want to use the circle again)
    circle = null; 
}
```